# Empty Cgroup entries in Nginx service status output on an Ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, cgroup

I am running multiple web application on a single server, using Nginx as the web server. After git pulling an update to one of the django based website, I restarted the Nginx server. To check if everything is running well, I ran the command `sudo service nginx status` which gave me this output.

```
ubuntu@myIp:~$ sudo service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-05-08 07:04:36 UTC; 1 day 6h ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
   Main PID: 42736 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1141)
     Memory: 7.7M
        CPU: 3.829s
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─42736 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             └─42737 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

May 08 07:04:36 myip systemd[1]: nginx.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 08 07:04:36 myip systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 08 07:04:36 myip systemd[1]: nginx.service: Consumed 6.079s CPU time.
May 08 07:04:36 myip systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 08 07:04:36 myip systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

What puzzles me are the multiple empty string entries in the CGroup pid 42737.
I tried to search on this but could not get anything substantial. All it says is that empty strings could represent:

1. The cgroup was recently created and no processes have yet been
   assigned to it.
2. The cgroup was previously used to manage a set of processes, but those processes have since exited or been terminated.
3. The cgroup was never used, and there are no processes running on the system that have been assigned to it.

Is this a matter of concern?

Comment: It typically means that the processes managed by that CGroup have either exited or have not been assigned to it yet. so it is OK and don't worry.
When a worker process is not actively serving a request, it may appear as an empty string entry in the CGroup, but this is just an artifact of how CGroups represent processes.